# sqlpackage publish fails if sqlcmd variable is not provided

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, sqlcmd, sqlpackage, sqlproj

I have an SQL project where I need to run certain scripts depending on the value of an SQLCMD variable
When I pass the variable on sqlpackage.exe (i.e. /v:var=value) it works as expected, but when I don't pass the variable it fails instead of using the default value I set:

> *** An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue. Missing values for the following SqlCmd
>   variables:var.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: define variable in publish profile and pass it to the sqlpackage

Comment: I prefer not to use publish profiles. I need a way for a variable to be a default value or a value provided to sqlpackage